# Need to log in twice to app deployed to Azure

Tags: azure

Our current setup in Azure is a load balancer and 2 servers, both hosting an MVC C# web site.
I can log in to the app no problem but I find I have to login multiple times.
The way I've deployed it to both servers is to build, publish locally and copy to both servers.   Is this the correct method?   Is there a way to propagate the login?

If not, how should it be done?

This is my first venture with deploying to Azure and multiple servers so any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if I understand: log in to your app, or into Azure? If it's your app: how are you managing logins? Central store (e.g. Redis cache / SQL Database)? If you're using some type of in-proc session management, you're going to have issues with multiple VMs (unless you force some type of VM affinity, which has its own set of issues)

Comment: When you say login, what kind of login is configured and how?

Comment: The logins are managed as part of the app (it's not an Azure login) which are checked against a database.  As I said, the login is fine but when I click on a menu option is goes right back to the login screen and I have to login again.   This is an MVC/nHibernate app.